I want df to return the space I want to simulate for a folder
I have a folder /backup whose df -h /backup output shows 200G available space, as I want 0 GB available and I dont want to add that much data in /backup folder. How can I achieve this? I dont want to add space using fallocate either.
Thanks

One approach is that you create a partition with the desired maximum volume and then mount the backup directory to that partition. But I'm not sure that this is what you really want...

Seems like df might be the wrong tool to measure what you envision.
